# How to add an icon in (implicit) list while using Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am developing J2ME app using NetBeans; I am created one List of menus using 'List' control and **List type is IMPLICIT**.

In that list there is a one menu named as Map. For this Map menu, I want to add an icon. I tried to do this and code is:

```
Image Mainlistmap;
try
{
        Mainlistmap = Image.createImage("/src/map.png");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

I have stored my entire project in following ditectory - `E:\MScIT Part 2\MobileLocationReminder`.

`MobileLocationReminder` folder is project folder that contains all the stuff of project such as src folder, dist folder, build folder, nbproject folder, build.xml file

I have stored icon in src folder of and icon name is map.png and size is 30X33.

I want to display a map.png icon to Map menu in the list but after doing all these things it is not giving me a desired result.

Where do I store an image icon to access my project correctly and what path should be given to access an image in project?